# How do I navigate using a symlink?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, terminal

How do I navigate using a symlink?

I created a symlink, let's say 'projects' to my '/Desktop/Work/Projects' folder. So if I type 'ls' in my root directory, I see a bunch of things, the symlink among them. 'cd projects' fails with the error:

```
-bash: cd: projects: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

The symlink is broken. If by 'your' `/Desktop/Work/Projects` you mean `/home/youruser/Desktop/Work/Projects`, then that's the path you should symlink to:

```
ln -s "/home/youruser/Desktop/Work/Projects" "/home/youruser/projects"
```

Comment: Thanks 'that other guy', how can I see where a symlink is currently pointing? (I want to check it's path)

Comment: ls -l projects shows he destinaion of the symlink